# django crash: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have an app that uses 1.9. It will work fine for weeks and weeks,
and then out of the blue a page that has just worked will crash with
this:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
in get_response
 174.                     response =
self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
in get_response
 172.                     response = response.render()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
 160.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in
rendered_content
 137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
in render
 95.             return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 204.                 with context.bind_template(self):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
 17.             return self.gen.next()

exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

Exception Location:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py in
import_string, line 23
```

If I go to the exact same URL again it will work.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this or how I can debug it further?

UPDATE:

The django code clearly has a bug, and I fixed it on my system. That allowed me to see the next higher up error, which was an error importing one of my own context_processors. This is odd, as the file and function are there, and are readable, and if they were not I would always get this error, not just get it intermittently. I still think there is another higher up error, and I tried to find it by setting a breakpoint and running the devel server, but with that the error never occurs.

Comment: Useless stack traces like this one are one of my major Django gripes.  Why can't they show the line of **my** code that caused the error?  Showing a bunch of Django internal modules doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback might provide a clue. Specifically the following line

```
exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
```

indicates that the crash was due to an improperly defined exception.

Comment: Yes, but this is in the django code, not in my code. So how can I find out what is happening in the app that causes this to surface sporadically, on pages that work almost all the time?